PhpStorm. How to change the background of the found words and the background of the line on the "Find in files"?
I want to change the colors in the "Find if files" window in PhpStorm:

Background color of found words
Background color of the current row


Please tell me where I can edit the background of the words I've found and the background of the search row in the "Find in files" window?

AFAIK it's part of the actual UI Theme (download another one (installs as a plugin) or make one yourself). That is not customisable via Color Scheme, which affects the Editor. I have custom colors for the search fragment in the Editor, and it's not the same as in the actual Find window. Anyway, the colors used for that in the Editor can be found at  Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme  -- General | Search Results and General | Editor | Caret row.

That's it! Got it, thank you.
